# How can I mount a dmg based filesystem for one specific process or user

Tags: filesystem, mount, dmg

I've got dmg file that formatted to HFS+ filesystem and i'd like to mount it with limited access rights.

Is it possible to create a mountpoint that will be accessible to specific user (by name) or specific process (by name/path/pid or any other identifier), so that other entities wouldn't have access to that mount drive ?

thanks